# How to display/query only the value after the first comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

| ID | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | lab1,lab2 |
| 124 | lab1 |

I have **Label** column filled with row values having commas and some does not have (ex. row 2)

I want to query or display both **ID** and **Label** columns but the **Label** column should only display the second value (value after the first comma) if commas are present. Else, display the only actual value if no commas are present.

Please note that I just want to query/display it only. I'm not making actual changes on the table itself.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI the version of SSMS you are using is mostly irrelevant, its the version of SQL Server (`select @@version`) that is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

just use this :

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delimiter, number)
```

The SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns a substring of a string before a specified number of delimiter occurs.

```
SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(label, ",", -1) FROM test
```

[try sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63cb8b/5)

Answer (score 0):

One method is rather brute force to get everything after the comma:

```
select t.*,
       (case when label like '%,%'
             then stuff(label, 1, charindex(',', label), '')
             else label
        end)
from t;
```

Another method is fancier and gets everything after the last comma:

```
select t.*,
       right(label, len(label) - charindex(',', reverse(label)));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29c8133155e0c12b170291c5b9d32a98) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command in SQL 18 and in both situations, you get the correct value.
If value of Label column has "," or not, you get the correct value as you want:

```
Select substring(label , charindex(',',label)+1,LEN(label)).
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using this command:

```
reverse(left(reverse(label),charindex(',',reverse(label))-1))
```

It's a little different than other codes, but gets you lab 2 each and every time with the perfect length